# Is It possible to serve a folder directly from azure storage using Function app with c# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

Is there any chance to serve a folder directly from Azure Storage using an Azure Function app with C# code, without downloading and listing all files locally?

Like directly what are all the files and folders are in Azure Storage, that should serve using function app?

I tried to serve one file directly from Azure Storage using function app and code in C#. But when I tried to serve the folder, I am unable to serve it, is there any chance to do it?

Comment: If that's static content, why not use a [CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cdn/)?

Comment: @Madhava, To serve those files into azure storage which trigger you are using?

Comment: @Madhava, Can you share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Like directly what are all the files and folders are in Azure Storage, that should serve using function app?

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack C#. I am able to access and serve the Folder within the azure storage container by using Http endpoint. below function code is worked fine.

**Function code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace FunctionApp1309023
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("ServeFolder")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "folders/{folderName}")] HttpRequest req,
            string folderName,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // Retrieve connection string from App Settings
            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage1");

            // Container name
            string containerName = "hellocont";

            // Create blob service client
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            // Get container client
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            // Get blobs in the folder
            var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: folderName + "/");

            // List blob names
            var fileList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var blobItem in blobs)
            {
                fileList.Add(blobItem.Name);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(fileList);
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage1":"your-storage conn-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

The Above function executed successfully. check below for the status:

[image]

**Output:**
[image]
[image]

In azure storage container folder details shown below:

[image]

Comment: Bro sorry to say this, Actually I tried this but I want serve entire folder is as a single entity.

Comment: Actually you have a folder named with WebApp in azure storage. when you run you Function app, the entire folder " WebApp " need to render instead URL. Actually I have a all HTML files are there in azure, that has some structure like a website. So when we run Function app that entire folder need to render on web. Is this possible  ?

Comment: yes, entire folder is possible.

Comment: May I know how to server entire folder directly from Azure storage Container?

Comment: In the above solution I was served entire folder.but getting all files inside folder. If you want that all as a folder that whole folder can be send to another folder in a container. That time can be possible to get whole folder.

Comment: Check in my container above there is two or more folders are there, able to serve all folders.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, let me explain clearly assume we have a folder, it contains HTML. That folder in Azure storage container, now is it possible to serve entire folder, when you run the function app those all files need to serve at a time. why I am asking this mean consider your HTML have some meta data and some structure etc... when you serve each file separately then, the original structure would not show, so I want to serve entire folder as a single entity, if we serve as a single entity then all reference file and structure everything serve at a time without any confusion.